# How to solve the following second-order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering how to solve the following second-order homogeneous ODE.

$$
tx''(t)+(2-2t)x'(t)=(\frac{\lambda}{t}-1)x(t)\quad t>0
$$
where $\lambda$ is a positive constant.

Comment: What have you tried?  Since you are dealing with nonconstant coefficients, you might first try to reduce the order.  If you can reduce to a first order equation, method of integrating factor might be an option.  Otherwise, you may need to try a clever ansatz.

Answer (score 1):

$$
tx''(t)+(2-2t)x'(t)=(\frac{\lambda}{t}-1)x(t)
$$
HINT :
Change of function 
$$x(t)=t^ay(bt)$$
Put it into the original ODE and identify to a Confluent Hypergeometric ODE. 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html

This leads to $a=\frac12(-1+\sqrt{4\lambda+1})$ and $b=2$.

The solution involves the Confluent Hypergeometric function of the second kind and/or some reduced form, such as associated Legendre polynomial for particular values of $\lambda$.

Comment: Hi Jean ! You are typing too fast for the old man !! Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Claude ! Glad to meet you. Cheers.